# Communicate the data or path from .sh file to .csh

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, csh

I am able to execute the .csh file from .sh file.
I want to pass the path from a.sh file to b.csh file when it starts to execute the .csh file.

eg:-

```
#a.sh
if(result=0) then
x=path/to/.csh 
#I want to pass the path from here for "a" 
#How can i do it? 
a=/my/path/1
elif(result=1) then
x=path/to/.csh 
a=/my/path/2
fi

#b.csh
set a=/path/to/add
```

Comment: I want to pass the path to a set a=/path/ from a.sh file

Comment: I want to override the path set a=/path/to/add    in b.csh file by passing it from the a.sh file. So how can i do it?

Comment: I want to pass or send data from .sh to .csh file, will I be able to override "set" in .csh file from .sh file?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are csh scripts so you can directly call `b.csh` from `a.sh`. Use `source b.csh` to do this.

By the way, you do realise that, despite its name, `a.sh` is not a `sh` script, but a `csh` script don't you...?

Comment: No it is 2 different script files. One is .csh and the other is .sh script file.

Comment: No! They are both C Shell script files, even though you've called one a `.sh` and the other a `.csh` - the file _name_ is irrelevant to the _content_

Comment: Okay so how can I send the data from .sh file when I invoke a .csh file in .sh file

Comment: That's not what you're showing us in this question